# Facebook developer server sided log in error

Tags: html, .net, facebook

Even though the app id I gave it is correct, and the redirect uri is an absolute one, and it matches the one that is on the app's setting page, when I try to log in to my website through facebook I get the following error:

```
The redirect_uri URL must be absolute
```

This is my log in button:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="LoginButton" ImageUrl="~/images/login.jpg" PostBackUrl="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={481180555313770}&redirect_uri={singular.somee.com}" runat="server" />
```

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove** the **curly brackets** `{}` from the `client_id` and the `redirect_uri` and **add** the **protocol** `http` or `https` to the url.

The final url looks like

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=481180555313770&redirect_uri=http://singular.somee.com
```

Now it works for me and Facebook does not show any error.

Comment: Thank you, this is working. I wonder why the official tutorial on facebook.com says to leave the curly brackets on.

Comment: I think the curly brackets in the Facebook documentation are just placeholder for the client_id and redirect_uri.